# ember.js - Reference controller variable in a JS function in Handlebars template

Tags: ember.js

I have a function in my_controller to get a list of names in an array and I have a typeahead bootstrap input in my template that uses the array in my_controller:

**my_controller:**

```
    names: function(){
        var names;
        Ember.$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/users',
            async: false,
            success: function(response){
                names = response["users"];
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
            }
        });
        return names;
    }.property('names')
```

**Handlebars template**

```
   <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA" {{bind-attr data=names}}>

   $('#people-search .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    prefetch: $(this).get("data") //also tried $(this).data and $(this).attr("data")
   });
```

How do I correctly get the bounded attr in my js function? Is there a way to call the names variable directly in the typeahead ajax initializer?

Comment: Does throwing that JQuery code directly in the template actually work? I didn't know that was possible... But i suspect you should be calling that code in your View instead, and then loading the data from your controller from there.

Comment: so you're saying move the jquery function to the templates corresponding view? and yes it does work with dummy data, and I'm just trying to put real data so it should still work. You think I still have to move the code? I feel like there has to be a way to do this...I just don't know the syntax

Comment: I'm just surprised it works. I tried googling for any examples of people doing something similar (javascript in an HBS template) but didn't find any, so I can't imagine it's "correct". I'll post an answer with the syntax that I believe should work.

Comment: Your current error isn't just because you're using `get("data")` instead of `get("names")` is it?

Answer (score 0):

You should move your typeahead initiallization to your view. To access the data from the controller, it would look something similar to the following (syntax may vary if using Ember-CLI):

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var names = this.get('controller.names');
        Ember.$('#people-search .typeahead').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
                prefetch: names
        });
    }
});
```

This code is untested, but the general idea should be there. The important bit is that you typically access the controller from the view using `this.get('controller')`

Comment: So, how would I access this view in my template? Is it something like `{{view 'view_name'}}`? How would I denote that it has `class="typeahead"`?

Comment: @peyterkim I meant this as being in the view for your page, not a standalone view. Are you using Ember-CLI? If so, you just name the file the same as your template/route/controller, put it in the app/views folder, and use `export default Ember.View.extend({` instead of the first line I have there. Personally though, I like Kalman's solution a little better since its reusable.

Comment: Yeah so how would the template file look like then?

Comment: Just put your input in there the same as you have it now: `<input class="typeahead" type="text" id="people-search">`. You dont need to do anything to "include" the view. It's the view thats creating the template here, not the other way around. I'm trying to find a good way to explain it, but can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable typeahead component

```
App.TypeaheadCompComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  makeItTypeAhead: function(){
    var names = this.get('namesInsideComp');
    this.$('.typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1,
      source: names 
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

with a corresponding component template

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/typeahead-comp">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Names" />
  </script>
```

and then use it in any other template as follows

```
{{ typeahead-comp namesInsideComp=names}}
```

Working example on jsbin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nowalaxuzu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: i like this approach because I need to reuse it. But i'm getting a "utils is not defined" error and it's not finding the names and it doesn't display the search bar.

Comment: for the search bar to show up I had to extend the TextField class instead. but still getting the utils not defined and the names.